# JQuery on click script triggers change detection - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a button on my site which adds an item to an array and then tries to assign an on click with jQuery to the new button by doing the following after the item is added to the array.

```
$(function()
{
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do something like change the color of an element
  });
});
```

using ngFor I loop through this array and spawn the buttons. The on click event works, however, it cause my angular change detection to trigger each time I click somewhere which respawns everything and discards the changes the script has made.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am new to angular & web development in general so please guys don't be too hard on me ;)

Comment: why dont you use the native click functions from angular?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are adding items of some sort to an array and for each item added you want a new button and a click handler. Do something like this:

```
<input #hello type="text"/> <!-- I'm guessing the values being added to the array are coming from an input but they could come from anywhere -->
<button (click)="addNewButton(hello.value)">
```

controller code:

```
this.values = []

addNewButton(value) {
  this.values = this.values.push(value)
  // this.values = [...this.values, value] // same thing without mutating the array
}
```

For the new buttons:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let value of values; index as i">
  <button (click)="newButtonClicked(value, i)">{{ value }}</button>
</ng-container>
```

And controller code for the new buttons:

```
newButtonClicked(value, i) {
  console.log(value, i)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be using the native Angular event binding paradigm to do this sort of stuff.

```
<div *ngFor="let person of roster" (click)="showPopup(person, $event)">
    <p>{{person.name}}</p>
    <button (click)="findOutMore(person)">Find out more</button>
<div>

public function showPopup(person: Person, event: any){
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
}

public findOutMore(person: Person){
    console.log("User wants to find out more about",person);
}
```

The only time I have ever personally required JQuery in an Angular app is when a 3rd party library that I want to use uses it.

You get a lot of great native functionality out of the box.

Comment: He is targeting a list of elements, it may be not suitable for his need. That is why I did not make any assumption and answer specifically to his question. Otherwise, your solution are the cleanest one.

Comment: What is the difference what type of element you are targeting? You can bind clicks this way to anything.

Comment: He was targeting `btn-add` class name elements.

Comment: @JonathanGagne Then he should create a new component and bind his click events as above as to encapsulate  this functionality and make it a reusable implementation.